# 'rosnode list' does not show the roscore in other computer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on two different Virtual Box.

I set the network mode as Bridge, that retrieves IP address from my router (Apple Airport).

The machine #1 has 10.0.1.24
The machine #2 has 10.0.1.25.

I ran the roscore in machine #1.
And 'rosnode list' on machine #2.

But I don't know why roscore of machine #1 does not show up in machine #2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9626/%27rosnode-list%27-does-not-show-the-roscore-in-other-computer./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2011-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-03**:
Can you edit your question to explain exactly what you're seeing and what you expect the output to be.  roscore is not itself a node and will not show up on rosnode list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set ROS_MASTER_URI as Martin said, but you may also need to set ROS_HOSTNAME. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines for a full tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2011-04-03**:
Thanks. Works well.